# rails-ujs permanently disabling the link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Steps to reproduce
I've created an anchor tag and used the data-confirm with data-disable-with but when I click on the tag it is showing the confirmation pop-up and disabling the button but after completing the request it is not enabling it again.

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure you want to remove this scorer?" data-disable-with="<i class='fa fa-spinner spinner_title'></i>" class="small red remove hover" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/events/event_id>
Remove</a>
```

Expected behavior
It should have to enable the button after completing the request.

Actual behavior
It is disabling the button but not enabling it after the request completion.

Could you please tell me why it is happening, because previously I've used `jquery-ujs` and it was working fine but after using `rails-ujs` it stops working.

> System configuration Rails version: Rails 5.2.0 Ruby version: Ruby -
>   2.5.1

Comment: I created a new Rails project with exactly the specified setup (Ruby and Rails versions) and tried the html example. You have an unclosed `href` attribute, but apart of this, it works perfectly. Therefore I suspect the issue is not about Rails' ujs but about your project's own js stepping in in an unexpected way.

Comment: Btw. do I get it right that by "using rails-ujs" you don't mean installing the deprecated `rails-ujs` gem, but simply retiring jquery-ujs and using what is packaged in Rails 5.2.0?

Comment: yes, I'm using rails-ujs packaged inside Rails 5.2.0

Comment: For anyone else finding this, there's more discussion on the cross-posted GitHub issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33889